# What happens to a disposed Task?

Tags: c#, task, idisposable, task-parallel-library

What happens to a local Task reference when it runs out of scope and the garbage collector decides to get rid of it before the task completes?

Basically I'm asking if it's safe to make this kind of service call implementation:

```
/// <summary>
/// Web service operation to start a large batch asynchronously
/// </summary>    
public StartBatchResponseMessage StartBatch(StartBatchRequestMessage request)
{
  Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(DoWork);
  return new StartBatchResponseMessage();
}

private void DoWork()
{
  // Implement solving world hunger here.
}
```

Will DoWork always complete in this example? Even if the garbage collector decides to dispose the Task instance variable t?

If not, what is a safer way to implement this kind of functionality?

Comment: be careful how you use the word 'disposed'. Don't get confused with the `IDisposable` pattern.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

yes, it will be run. If you decompile your code you can see the call to `Task.Factory.StartNew` calls `Task.InternalStartNew`, which calls `Task.ScheduleAndStart(false)`.

This in turn calls `task.m_taskScheduler.QueueTask(this),` which according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.queuetask.aspx) adds the task to an internal structure - which will of course stop it from being garbage collected. Which is exactly as you'd hope.

Comment: This is an even more in depth description of what happens. Thought it would work that way, but never hurts to be sure. Thanks! Is this the reason you're not being warned to run tasks within a using statement?

Comment: That's interesting - I'm ashamed to admit I hadn't even noticed Task implemented IDisposable. It certainly wouldn't work to put it in a using statement as the entire point of it is to be asynchronous. If you call dispose on it when it hasn't finished or been cancelled you get an exception thrown apparently so using(Task t = newTask){} would throw an exception on exiting the using block I think (unless it was completed by then, or cancelled)

Comment: That suggests that you could use a using statement to verify a task has completed when doing a certain job, or else throw an exception. Could be useful in some cases.. I guess.

Comment: I can't really see it being useful for that as the task is being run asynchronously so it'd just be pure luck as to whether your app threw an exception or not on exiting the using block. If you wanted to make sure the task had completed you would need to join on it.

Comment: Joining is a blocking call so that's not the same. I can imagine cases in which you really want a task to be done in a certain amount of time, or in a certain amount of other work being done. If not done in this block of code: just cancel the task and log the exception being thrown.

Answer (score 3):

Common sense, you know. The Task library has to somehow call your method, so - it has to keep a reference, otherwise it could not call it. So, obviously, this reference prevents garbage collection.

Basically the "Task" you get is your pointer to the Task object that the internal execution engine also has to have a reference to, otherwise it would never get executed.

So, as there are references OTHER than your t variable, so it won't be disposed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the task will always complete. The garbage collector is not going to get to its relevant parts while the task is running.